# MariaDB - can't create a table with two foreign keys

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have following query:

```
create table bans
(
    id int auto_increment primary key ,
    reason int not null,
    player int not null,
    server int not null,
    starts timestamp default current_timestamp not null,
    ends DATETIME not null,
    constraint bans__fk_player
        foreign key (player) references players ('id'),
    constraint bans__fk_server
        foreign key (server) references servers ('id')
);
```

Which results in:

```
[2019-01-02 18:35:29] [42000][1064] (conn=75) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''id'),
[2019-01-02 18:35:29] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''id'),
```

---

I just want to make 1:n relation between:

`players.id` -> `bans.player`
and name it `bans__fk_player`

`servers.id` -> `bans.server`
and name it `bans__fk_server`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Comment: Remove quotes from `('id')`

Comment: @forpas After removing the quotes: Can't create table `banAPI`.`bans` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: @MxnaXV0S see this https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/foreign-keys/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) This was commented already by SO folks : you need to remove the quotes around your identifiers in the foreign keys definition. Also see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql) for a general discussion about using quotes in mysql/MariaDB.

2) Another issue is that you are not defining the constraint properly, it is missing a name for the  foreign key. The syntax is as folllows, as explained in [this mysql turorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/) :

```
CONSTRAINT constraint_name
FOREIGN KEY foreign_key_name (columns)
REFERENCES parent_table(columns)
```

So your code should be :

```
...
constraint bans__player
    foreign key bans__fk_player (player) references players (id),
constraint bans__server
    foreign key bans__fk_server (server) references servers (id)
...
```

See [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j33DZd6ugVuHyJzfaQMrVw/0).

This should work as well, and produces a shorter syntax (you probably don’t need to explicitly name the constraints) :

```
...
foreign key bans__fk_player (player) references players (id),
foreign key bans__fk_server (server) references servers (id)
...
```

If you are still experiencing errors, then you have to look at the definition of the referenced tables (servers and players). In both tables, id must be either the primary key of the table, or must be controlled by a unique constraint. And of course, it must be numeric.

Comment: create table bans
    (
         id int auto_increment primary key ,
         reason int not null,
         player int not null,
         server int not null,
         starts timestamp default current_timestamp not null,
         ends DATETIME not null,
         constraint bans__player
           foreign key bans__fk_player (player) references players (id),
         constraint bans__server
           foreign key bans__fk_server (server) references servers (id)
     );
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `banAPI`.`bans` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: @MxnaXV0S : it works... I added a db fiddle to my answer, along with more information

Comment: @MxnaXV0S : Ok, It seems silly but server.id was named server.server_id and that was causing the issue. Thanks for help!

Comment: Welcome @MxnaXVS0S

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quote the column `id`, in MariaDB (also in MySQL) you should use "back ticks", as in:

```
create table bans
(
    id int auto_increment primary key ,
    reason int not null,
    player int not null,
    server int not null,
    starts timestamp default current_timestamp not null,
    ends DATETIME not null,
    constraint bans__fk_player
        foreign key (player) references players (`id`),
    constraint bans__fk_server
        foreign key (server) references servers (`id`)
);
```